# Mysql show other different cell data with under group by same name

Tags: mysql, group-by

Let's assume I have a table which store register user data, the records might have same registered name but different email, like following:

[image]

I want to create a front view to manipulate those data but I don't want those same name show repeatedly, can mysql statement query to output result like

[image]

this is the result so far I can do but it can't bind same name into one.

```
    select * from `register` 
    where `fullname` in ( 
              select `fullname` from `register` 
              group by `fullname` having count(*) > 1 
    )
```

Comment: Do you have permission to have data from David De Gea? GDPR..

Comment: I'd do it on the front end while displaying the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to do a `SELECT DISTINCT` on the duplicate row, and make use of the `GROUP_CONCAT();` function in MYSQL to *concatenate* your desired values into one row, and `GROUP BY fullname` to get the order you wanted.

Note that I am also putting the *user ids* into a grouped row, so that you can track which *ids* belong to which name.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT fullname as full_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') as user_ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(email SEPARATOR ', ') as emails
FROM 
  tbl_register
GROUP BY
  tbl_register.fullname
```

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfafb4/1)

This would be the logical way to do it. Hope this helped. :)

More information on the `GROUP_CONCAT();` function here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *duplicate_column* FROM *table_name1* WHERE *col_id* IN (SELECT *cols_to_dusplay* FROM *table_name1* GROUP_BY *duplicate_column*
```